# JIRA Burn Down and Burn Up together

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

we are using JIRA and Agile Board so we estimate the user stories with story points and JIRA takes care about burn down.

However we have also Tasks (not in user stories but single tasks) and bugs which can not be estimated in story points. After we solve those, we are estimating "work done" in terms of our story points and document them as "comments" in the tickets (bug or task)

Is there any plugin or tool, which can build a kind of burn up chart only for those (bugs and tasks) so that we can keep track.

At the end of a sprint, we do not have only burn down, but we also burn up and the effective real effort is the sum of those two.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to create a search that returned the issue types you were interested in and then export the data to Excel. You could then generate the burn up chart that you want.

I should note that you are not using story points in the usual Scrum fashion. Bugs and tasks are not usually counted in the team's velocity. They represent an overhead which reduces the team's ability to deliver stories (which are where business value is added).

Remember that velocity is not a measure of work done. It is instead a metric used to help with estimating what the team's capacity for delivering business value is in future sprints.

Comment: It is true that Story Points counted only for Stories, bugs and tasks are not counted. We do it also in that way. However, my approach is, to find the "real" work done after a sprint. We do not estimate Bugs and Tasks in before, but after it has been finished the developer writes down SP for the work done.